# Concern специфичный для конкретной модели. Circular dependency detected while autoloading

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Попытался добавить concern для конкретной модели как в данном проекте:

https://github.com/catarse/catarse/blob/master/app/models/concerns/user/omniauth_handler.rb

https://github.com/catarse/catarse/blob/master/app/models/user.rb

Получаю ошибку `Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant ModelName::ConcernsName`. Правда только на production.

Для решения проблемы я обернул

```
module Concerns
  module ModelName::ConcernsName
  end
end
```

и соотвественно `include Concerns::ModelName::ConcernsName`

Почему это работает в Catarse?

P.S. Ошибка возникает только для двух из 4-х моделей. При этом классифицировать их я не могу.

P.P.S Полностью очистив от кода модуль примесь и класс модели, для которого возникает ошибка - ошибка сохраняется. Так что это врядли зависит от их содержимого.

Comment: А у вас версия Rails какая?

Comment: версия rails 4.2.6